# Difference between multiple Python 3 interpreters after install on fresh Macbook Pro via Homebrew?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

**Questions**

1. What are the meaningful differences between the following two Python interpreters apparently[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiMbt.png) installed on my machine (2019 MacBook Pro with Catalina)?

   - `usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7`
   - `usr/local/bin/python3`
2. Most importantly, which should I select as the interpreter for my IDE (Visual Studio Code)?
3. Which interpreter is employed when running `$ python3` in terminal?

**Context**

- I just got a new 2019 MacBook Pro with OSX Catalina and noticed it came with a Python 2.7.10 interpreter installed.
- I [installed Python 3 via Homebrew](https://wsvincent.com/install-python3-mac/) given I mainly want to use Python 3 for my projects.

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiMbt.png) I discovered these interpreters upon attempting to change the interpreter used by Visual Studio Code. Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7` is where Homebrew put the `python3.7` executable (as a symlink) and then Homebrew made the more generic `/usr/local/bin/python3` symlink. They point to the same executable. I would choose the `python3.7` one as that's tied to a more specific Python version (but I actually more strongly recommend creating a virtual environment and using that).